# OpenSeaDragon clear tiles cache

Tags: openseadragon

Please help me. How can I clear tiles cache. 
I'm using customTilesSource and changing paramenters of image "on fly" and need redraw viewer.

By API in TileCache there isnnt direct method for clear all cache. 
For using clearTilesFor(tiledImage) I need to know tiledImage, but I dont know how to get tiledImage

Answer (score 0):

To clear all tiles for all images do `viewer.world.resetItems()`.

http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/OpenSeadragon.World.html#resetItems